# Emberjs DOM Exception 8 error on view that is called through conditional operator

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am building an Ember app where I have to swap out a navigation view based on whether or not a user is logged in. The conditional redirect works, but I get a DOM exception 8 error whenever the router moves from the logged out state to the logged in state.

If I don't do a navigation swap, then the template renders correctly on transition. Or if I refresh the page manually, then it will render, which of course I don't want to have to do it that way. The error only seems to occur when I place conditional operators for rendering a view. I place all my conditionals either in the router or in the controller.

Has anybody else run into this issue, and if so, how did you solve it? Also, I was reading in the source that there is a method called disconnectOutlet. Has anybody used this or have advice on how I would call this in the code? Thanks!!